# How to get dataset from MySql procedure using mysqli PHP

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

i have a problem when i want to get a dataset from Mysql Procedure using PHP
this my code :

```
//This is how i connect to database using mysqli
    $Condb = @new MySQLi(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
    $Condb->connect_errno and die ('Connect Failed : '.$Condb->connect_error);
    $this->Condb = $Condb;

//This how i call the procedure
$stmt = $Condb->query("CALL GET_DATA_PRODUK(" . $import_value . ")");
if(!$stmt){
    echo "CALL Procedure Failed : " . $Condb->errno . " " . $Condb->error;
}else{
    $return_value;
    while ($tabResultat = $stmt->fetch_array()){
    $return_value[] = $tabResultat;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
$Condb->close();
echo "<pre>" . print_r($return_value,true) . "</pre>";
```

This is the result i get :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [kd_merek] => 1
            [1] => Carvil
            [nama] => Carvil
            [2] => Merek Carvil merek yang sudah dikenal, enak dipakai dengan harga yang terjangkau




Carvil.. Tetap Yang Terbaik
            [deskripsi] => Merek Carvil merek yang sudah dikenal, enak dipakai dengan harga yang terjangkau




Carvil.. Tetap Yang Terbaik
            [3] => 2
            [rating] => 2
            [4] => 23
            [user_id] => 23
        )
```

this is the result i want to get :

[image]

i just only get one row of result
can someone help me how to get all row of result from the procedure

Comment: Your procedure returns all datasets?

Comment: when i try execute at mysql, that procedure return all dataset as image attached at question

Comment: Can't see how you'd get that print_r output, since your while() loop is only saving the `nama` parameter of the result set.

Comment: @MarcB : i have edited my question..the result that i put inside question is output of print_r